# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [project.dao.ServiceUserDao] found for dependency

Tags: java, spring, controller, javabeans, autowired

I have some problem with my Hibernate Spring project. I tried to add some Qualifiers or change base-package, but it doesnt help.

Error

```
2015-11-08 11:20:33.176  INFO 9586 --- [           main] project.Main                             : Starting Main on localhost.localdomain with PID 9586 (/home/kristyna/Dokumenty/ProjectWeb/target/classes started by kristyna in /home/kristyna/Dokumenty/ProjectWeb)
2015-11-08 11:20:33.223  INFO 9586 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@75cd8043: startup date [Sun Nov 08 11:20:33 CET 2015]; root of context hierarchy
2015-11-08 11:20:34.072  INFO 9586 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'beanNameViewResolver': replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.class]]
2015-11-08 11:20:34.716  INFO 9586 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2015-11-08 11:20:34.964  INFO 9586 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2015-11-08 11:20:34.965  INFO 9586 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.28
2015-11-08 11:20:35.120  INFO 9586 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2015-11-08 11:20:35.120  INFO 9586 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1902 ms
2015-11-08 11:20:35.778  INFO 9586 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean        : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2015-11-08 11:20:35.783  INFO 9586 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2015-11-08 11:20:35.784  INFO 9586 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2015-11-08 11:20:35.852  WARN 9586 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'webController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void project.web.WebController.setServiceUserDao(project.dao.ServiceUserDao); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [project.dao.ServiceUserDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:759)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:117)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:689)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:969)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:958)
    at project.web.Application.run(Application.java:13)
    at project.Main.main(Main.java:24)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void project.web.WebController.setServiceUserDao(project.dao.ServiceUserDao); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [project.dao.ServiceUserDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:649)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [project.dao.ServiceUserDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1047)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:606)
    ... 24 common frames omitted

2015-11-08 11:20:35.855  INFO 9586 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service Tomcat
2015-11-08 11:20:35.866  INFO 9586 --- [           main] .b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_51/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar, file:/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_51/jre/lib/deploy.jar, file:/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_51/jre/lib/jce.jar, file:/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_51/jre/lib/charsets.jar, file:/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_51/jre/lib/plugin.jar, file:/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_51/jre/lib/rt.jar, file:/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_51/jre/lib/management-agent.jar, file:/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_51/jre/lib/resources.jar, file:/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_51/jre/lib/jsse.jar, file:/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_51/jre/lib/javaws.jar, file:/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_51/jre/lib/jfr.jar, file:/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_51/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar, file:/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_51/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar, file:/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_51/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar, file:/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_51/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar, file:/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_51/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar, file:/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_51/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar, file:/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_51/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar, file:/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_51/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar, file:/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_51/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar, file:/home/kristyna/Dokumenty/ProjectWeb/target/classes/, file:/home/kristyna/Dokumenty/ProjectWeb/lib/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar, file:/home/kristyna/Dokumenty/ProjectWeb/lib/hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.2.Final.jar, file:/home/kristyna/Dokumenty/ProjectWeb/lib/antlr-2.7.7.jar, file:/home/kristyna/Dokumenty/ProjectWeb/lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar, file:/home/kristyna/Dokumenty/ProjectWeb/lib/jboss-logging-3.1.0.GA.jar, file:/home/kristyna/Dokumenty/ProjectWeb/lib/javassist-3.15.0-GA.jar, file:/home/kristyna/Dokumenty/ProjectWeb/lib/hibernate-core-4.2.2.Final.jar, file:/home/kristyna/Dokumenty/ProjectWeb/lib/jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar, file:/home/kristyna/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf/1.2.7.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf-1.2.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/kristyna/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/1.2.7.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-1.2.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/kristyna/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.2.7.RELEASE/spring-boot-1.2.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/kristyna/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/4.1.8.RELEASE/spring-context-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/kristyna/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.2.7.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.2.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/kristyna/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/1.2.7.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.2.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/kristyna/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.12/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.12.jar, file:/home/kristyna/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.12/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.12.jar, file:/home/kristyna/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.7.12/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.12.jar, file:/home/kristyna/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.3/logback-classic-1.1.3.jar, file:/home/kristyna/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.1.3/logback-core-1.1.3.jar, file:/home/kristyna/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.14/snakeyaml-1.14.jar, file:/home/kristyna/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/1.2.7.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-web-1.2.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/kristyna/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/1.2.7.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.2.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/kristyna/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/8.0.28/tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar, file:/home/kristyna/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-el/8.0.28/tomcat-embed-el-8.0.28.jar, file:/home/kristyna/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-logging-juli/8.0.28/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-8.0.28.jar, file:/home/kristyna/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/8.0.28/tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.28.jar, file:/home/kristyna/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.4.6/jackson-databind-2.4.6.jar, file:/home/kristyna/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.4.6/jackson-annotations-2.4.6.jar, file:/home/kristyna/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.4.6/jackson-core-2.4.6.jar, file:/home/kristyna/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.1.3.Final/hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar, file:/home/kristyna/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar, file:/home/kristyna/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.1.3.GA/jboss-logging-3.1.3.GA.jar, file:/home/kristyna/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.0.0/classmate-1.0.0.jar, file:/home/kristyna/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/4.1.8.RELEASE/spring-web-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/kristyna/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/4.1.8.RELEASE/spring-aop-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/kristyna/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar, file:/home/kristyna/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/4.1.8.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/kristyna/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/4.1.8.RELEASE/spring-expression-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/kristyna/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/4.1.8.RELEASE/spring-core-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/kristyna/.m2/repository/org/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring4/2.1.4.RELEASE/thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/kristyna/.m2/repository/org/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/2.1.4.RELEASE/thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/kristyna/.m2/repository/ognl/ognl/3.0.8/ognl-3.0.8.jar, file:/home/kristyna/.m2/repository/org/javassist/javassist/3.18.1-GA/javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar, file:/home/kristyna/.m2/repository/org/unbescape/unbescape/1.1.0.RELEASE/unbescape-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/kristyna/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.12/slf4j-api-1.7.12.jar, file:/home/kristyna/.m2/repository/nz/net/ultraq/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-layout-dialect/1.2.9/thymeleaf-layout-dialect-1.2.9.jar, file:/home/kristyna/.m2/repository/org/apache/derby/derbyclient/10.12.1.1/derbyclient-10.12.1.1.jar, file:/home/kristyna/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/4.1.6.RELEASE/spring-tx-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/kristyna/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.1.8.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/kristyna/Sta%c5%been%c3%a9/idea-IU-141.1532.4/lib/idea_rt.jar]
2015-11-08 11:20:35.869  INFO 9586 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report enable debug logging (start with --debug)


2015-11-08 11:20:35.870 ERROR 9586 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'webController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void project.web.WebController.setServiceUserDao(project.dao.ServiceUserDao); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [project.dao.ServiceUserDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:759)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:117)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:689)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:969)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:958)
    at project.web.Application.run(Application.java:13)
    at project.Main.main(Main.java:24)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void project.web.WebController.setServiceUserDao(project.dao.ServiceUserDao); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [project.dao.ServiceUserDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:649)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [project.dao.ServiceUserDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1047)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:606)
    ... 24 common frames omitted

Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'webController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void project.web.WebController.setServiceUserDao(project.dao.ServiceUserDao); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [project.dao.ServiceUserDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:759)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:117)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:689)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:969)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:958)
    at project.web.Application.run(Application.java:13)
    at project.Main.main(Main.java:24)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void project.web.WebController.setServiceUserDao(project.dao.ServiceUserDao); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [project.dao.ServiceUserDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:649)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [project.dao.ServiceUserDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1047)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:606)
    ... 24 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Controller

```
@Controller
public class WebController {

    private ServiceUserDao serviceUserDaoImpl;

    @Autowired
    public void setServiceUserDao(ServiceUserDao serviceUserDaoImpl) {
        this.serviceUserDaoImpl = serviceUserDaoImpl;
    }
```

Service

```
@Service
public class ServiceUserDaoImpl implements ServiceUserDao {

    UserDao userDao;

    @Autowired
    public void setServiceUserDao(UserDao userDao) {
        this.userDao = userDao;
    }
```

Dao

```
@Repository
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {

    private Session session;

    public UserDaoImpl(){
        this.session = Main.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
    }
```

I searched my problem and I didn't find something useful.
Thank you

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">

    <!-- Scan the JavaConfig -->
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="project" />
    <aop:config proxy-target-class="true"/>

    <bean
            class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name = "sessionFactory" ref = "sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:advice id="txAdvice">
        <tx:attributes>
            <tx:method name="*" propagation="REQUIRED" />
        </tx:attributes>
    </tx:advice>

    <aop:config>
        <aop:advisor pointcut="execution(* project..*.*(..))" advice-ref="txAdvice" />
    </aop:config>

</beans>
```

Comment: please, add your spring context configuration

Comment: Maybe you could also format into a block the error messages. Anyway, welcome to Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you validate that the `"project"` inside `<context:component-scan base-package="project" />` really is the package name where `@Service`s, `@Controller` classes are?

Another problem you might get after solving the `ServiceUserDao` is
that you get  `UserDaoImpl` can't get autowirred. This is because you haven't enabled the scanning of `@Repository`. If i remember right the `<context:annotation-config/>` isn't scanning for JPA stuff.

So try to add:

```
<beans:beans  ...
    ...
    xsi:schemaLocation="....
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">

<!-- Scan @Repositories -->
<repositories base-package="xxx.repositories" />
```

Comment: I didn't have Controller in the same package with Service. Now it works, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's the cause of your problem but there is a duplication in your spring context :

```
<context:annotation-config/>
```

is equivalent to :

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>
```

Did you post the full stack trace ?

Comment: I didn't post the full stack trace, because it repeats same error more times. The line before error is: 2015-11-08 11:20:35.852  WARN 9586 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt

Comment: when I remove duplication, it causes the same error

Comment: can you edit your question to add the full stack trace anyway .

Answer (score 0):

http://www.baeldung.com/spring-nosuchbeandefinitionexception
You can see this article, it maybe helpful for you.

2.Cause: No qualifying bean of type […] found for dependency
The most common cause of this exception is simply trying to inject a bean that isn’t defined.

```
@Component
public class BeanA{
@Autowired
private BeanB dependency;
//...
}
```

Now, if the dependency – BeanB – is not defined in the Spring Context, the bootstrap process will fail with the no such bean definition exception:

org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:

No qualifying bean of type [org.baeldung.packageB.BeanB] found for dependency: 
expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. 
Dependency annotations:{@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}